# How to assign default values on visualforce page for a sites form

Tags: visualforce, case

I am an experienced admin trying my hand at visualforce for the first time (no coding background).
Our use case is we want to use Salesforce Sites to create a simple form that will create a case record.
SF Sites requires using visualforce pages, so I've started creating my first VF page.
So far all the fields that I want the person to fill in on the form, I've been able to add to the form.
But I have a few fields like record type, case type and 2 lookup fields that I want to set as a default value . The person filling out the form will not see them- they will be hidden.

I haven't quite found how to do this and might be using the wrong terminology to search.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: The site does not require VF - see https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/build-forms for guidance. If the purpose of building this form is to build quickly with as little code as possible, take a look at Experience Cloud Customer Service template https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_napili_views.htm&type=5

Comment: or even - web-to-case if you have an existing website where you'd like to add a create-a-case link

Comment: I will clarify my post. I need a web form that lives outside of saleforce and is available to random people with no login to salesforce. I have no website. Just need a URL webform not attached to anything- hence using Sites.
I wish flow or web2case was an option but it is not. 
Unless you are telling me that I can use a screenflow on a Site and it will work for non- users, but i don't see that written in the link you sent

Comment: I am following this setup : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sites_setup_overview.htm&type=5

Comment: Both web2case and sites (Community, now Digital Experience Site) allow for unauthenticated users and forms. Flows can be added to sites for unauthenticated users: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_external.htm&type=5 . Please do a search here, there are lots of Q&A on this and/or check the links in these comments. If you're still stuck after attempting an implementation, edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)